# D3 transition isFinitDatae error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’m new to D3.js & am trying to add a transition to an svg color change, but I’m getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: isFinitDatae is not defined**.

The svg circles that need to change color are set up like this:

```
var markers = mapContainer.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(mapLayer2.features)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d){ 
                        return projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0],d.geometry.coordinates[1]])[0];    
                    })                                          
                    .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0],d.geometry.coordinates[1]])[1]; })
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .style("fill", function(d,i){
                        if(d.properties.entero_100ml_1 > 35){
                            return "#ff0000"
                        } else {
                            return "#ffcc00"
                        }
                    });
```

I have multiple buttons, and the color changes depend on which button is clicked. I tested clicking all of the buttons multiple times, and the color changes always work properly with this code:

```
var updateMarkers = function(enteroString)
{
    markers.data(mapLayer2.features)
            .style("fill", function(d,i){

                var keyArray = d3.keys(d.properties); 
                var valueArray = d3.values(d.properties);

                for (var j = 0; j < keyArray.length; j++){

                    if(keyArray[j] === enteroString){
                        if(valueArray[j] > 35){
                                    return "#ff0000";
                                } else {
                                    return "#ffcc00";
                                }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

…but when I add transition, duration & ease the transition only works the first time a button is clicked, and the “Uncaught ReferenceError: isFinitDatae is not defined” is thrown:

```
var updateMarkers = function(enteroString)
{
    markers.data(mapLayer2.features)
            .transition() 
            .duration(500) 
            .ease("quad")
            .style("fill", function(d,i){

                var keyArray = d3.keys(d.properties); 
                var valueArray = d3.values(d.properties);

                for (var j = 0; j < keyArray.length; j++){

                    if(keyArray[j] === enteroString){
                        if(valueArray[j] > 35){
                                    return "#ff0000";
                                } else {
                                    return "#ffcc00";
                                }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Any ideas about how to fix the error, since this is working without the transition?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

UPDATE: & here's where the updateMarkers is called:

```
chartContainer.selectAll("#xAxis text") 
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(10,0)";
        })
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", function(d,i) {
            var num = i + 1; 
            var numString = num.toString();
            var enteroString = "entero_100ml_" + numString;

            updateMarkers(enteroString);
        });
```

Comment: So where are you calling `isFinitDatae`?

Comment: Sorry, calling? I'm new to this so maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I'm not calling isFinitDatae like a function. It's an error message that's logging to the console when updateMarkers is run with transition on button click.

Comment: Yes, the error message is telling you that `isFinitDatae` is not defined. So where in your code does it occur?

Comment: Thanks...isFinitDatae occurs in D3.js, but not in JS that I wrote. Not sure how I would define it, b/c in other D3 animations I've seen that happens automatically when you call transition().

Comment: OK, I just compared the D3.js version I was testing with to the latest and it looks like “isFinitDatae” could be some kind of typo b/c there’s only “isFinite” in the latest version. Transitions work with the latest version. Thank you Lars, your questions put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

"isFinitDatae" is a typo in the version of D3 I was testing with. In the latest version it's "isFinite", and transitions are working.